# Laravel 8: How to return questions that have answers by withCount()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my forum, and I want to return the questions that have answers.

So I added `withCount()` to my method which goes here:

```
public function index()
    {
        $questions = Question::latest()->limit(5)->get();
        $topAnswered = Question::withCount('answers')->get();
        dd($topAnswered);
    }
```

So `$topAnswered` should contain the questions that have already answered but it returns also some questions that have not answered yet!

So I need to fix that but don't know how to do that...

Note that I have this relation at the `Question` Model:

```
public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }
```

And this one also at the `Answer` Model:

```
public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }
```

So if you know, how to return only the questions that have already answered, please let me know, I would really appreciate that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll be needing the `having` function be used as another selector in there

```
$topAnswered = Question::withCount('answers')->having('answers_count', '>', 0)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `whereHas`

```
Question::whereHas('answers', function(Builder $query) {
   $query->where(...) //You condition where some questions that have not answered yet
})->get();
```

Or with `has`:

```
Question::has('answers', 0)->get();
```

You can read this section of the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Comment: I like that answer too. There's many different ways to handle data in Laravel & Symfony so you just pick one that works and go with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think using has() is the best solution:

```
public function index()
    {
        $topAnswered = Post::has('answers_count', '>', 0)->withCount('answers')->take(5)->get();
       
        dd($topAnswered);
    }
```